# How to split a ranking (table) after 20 entries and see the next at the next site?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, row, ranking

I want to stop the row after 20 entries and return at the same point at the next side. To make it short I want only 20 entries per site.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>server ranking</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
</head>

<body>
<?PHP
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Fehler bei der datenbank");
              mysql_select_db("users") or die ("datenbank existiert nicht")
?>

<?PHP
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM `ranking` ORDER BY `points` DESC ";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
$zaehler = 0;
?>
<table rules="all" style="90%;">
  <caption>ViceVice Server Ranking</caption>

  <tr style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
    <td>Rang</td>
    <td>Benutzername</td>
    <td>Punkte</td>
  </tr>

<?PHP
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
  {
    $zaehler = $zaehler + 1;
?>

  <tr>

    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width: 50;">

      <?PHP
        echo $zaehler;
      ?>

    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width: 50;">

      <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/<?php echo $row->user; ?>/25.png">

    </td>
    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; width: 200;">

      <?PHP
        echo $row->user;
      ?>

    </td>
    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; width: 100;">

      <?PHP
        echo $row->points;
      ?>

    </td>

  </tr>

<?PHP
  }
?>

</table>


</body>
</html>


I would thank you for any help ;D
```

Comment: What do you mean _20 entrys_ **per site**?

Comment: "and return at the same point at the next side" I dont understand, do you mean on another page?

Comment: on the first side you have the rank from 1-20 at the second side the rank from 21-30 and so on. the database has more then 5.000 entrys if you want to know

Comment: Are you asking a question about pagination? You want a table to show 20 entries, with "next" and "back" buttons/links?

Comment: Sorry yes I mean this. When I would create complete new pages I would only ask for help with the limit but in the databse are like I said more then 5.000 entrys so I would create sites until my life ends. ;D

Comment: The answer is quite long, so I will give you help with what to look for... You can use LIMIT in your mysql query to tell mysql to return only a subsection of the results. For example SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10,20 means show me 20 records, starting from the 10th. You can combine this with URL parameters in your "back" and "next" links: www.example.com/mypage.php?start=10&show=20. Use those parameters (found in the $_GET array) to dynamically create your mysql query. This way, you only need one page, and you can decide which records to show using those URL parameters. Hope this helps you start

Comment: Does this really work? Because I sorted the database in the same code..... Can you give me an exampel how I should use this with my code above?

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as a definitive answer, because there are many ways to accomplish what the OP is asking. It is, however, too long to post as a comment. This method uses simple URL parameters to specify the pagination (`start` shows the record to start at, `show` specifies how many records to show), and MySQL's `LIMIT` clause to limit the database output. Obviously **you must check that the values in the $_GET parameters are reasonable**. If the user changes the URL to read `page.php?start=hello&show=world` your query will fail... I have left out the data sanitation for brevity.

**page.php:**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, description FROM mytable ORDER BY id";

// if there is the "start" url parameter, use it. Else, start from zero.
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;

// if there is the "show" url parameter, user it. Else, use default 20 records.
$show = isset($_GET['show']) ? $_GET['show'] : 20;

$sql .= " LIMIT $start,$show";

// doDatabaseQuery is a fictitious function which we assume
// returns an array of objects. Comment this line if using test data, below
$records = doDatabaseQuery($sql); 

// if you want to test this with some fake data, uncomment this code section
// which creates 200 fake records, and puts them into an
// array then array_slice acts like the "LIMIT" clause in the mysql query
/*
for($x=1;$x<=200;$x++) {
    $o = new stdClass();
    $o->id = $x;
    $o->description = "Description for object $x";

    $records[] = $o;
}

$records = array_slice($records, $start, $show);
*/

// set the "start" parameter value in the "Back" link
// if it's less than zero, we set it to zero.
$previous_start = $start - $show;
if($previous_start < 0) $previous_start = 0;

// set the "start" parameter value in the "Next" link
// if we wanted to do something more advanced, we would check
// this value is not greater than the number of records in the table
$next_start = $start + $show;

include "page.html";
?>
```

**page.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Pagination Page</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php for($i=0; $i < count($records); $i++): ?>                    
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $records[$i]->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $records[$i]->description; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="page.php?start=<?php echo $previous_start;?>&amp;show=<?php echo $show;?>">Back</a></td>
                    <td><a href="page.php?start=<?php echo $next_start;?>&amp;show=<?php echo $show;?>">Next</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
       </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Advantages:** Allows a very basic pagination, but can be easily adapted to provide "Last Page" and "First Page" functionality.

**Disadvantages:** Allows the user to manipulate the URL by hand; imagine a table with 2000000 records - the user could set the `show` parameter to 2000000 and have your server do lots of work to pull out all the records from the table... To get around this, you can limit the `$show` variable in the code to a maximum value, or remove it from the URL completely and keep it at a fixed value.